# Issue adding date created to order number when creating order manually in WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, date, woocommerce, backend, orders

I use the following code to modify the order number in WooCommerce.

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_number', 'change_woocommerce_order_number', 1, 2);

function change_woocommerce_order_number( $order_id, $order ) {
    $prefix = '160-';
    // you will need to get your city as a variable to pass in to priffix 
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    $order_date = $order->get_date_created();
    $date_created = $order_date->date( 'Ymd' );
    
   
    // You can use either one of $order->id (or) $order_id
    // Both will wor
    return $prefix . $order->id . '-'.$date_created;
}
```

This code works during the checkout process but I get an error like this when i manually create an order in WooCommerce backend.

[image]

How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code contains some mistakes

- The use `$order = wc_get_order( $order_id );`is not necessary, as `$order` already passed to the function
- `$order->id` has been replaced since WooCommerce 3 (2017) with `$order->get_id()`
- However, using/replacing `$order->get_id()` is not needed in this answer, as this is also passed to the function
- The **error will not occur when you place an order, but will occur when you want to create a new order** in the backend (which is the case for you). Simply because the order has yet to be created, and that value does not yet exist

So you get

```php
function filter_woocommerce_order_number( $order_number, $order ) { 
    // Prefix
    $prefix = '160-';
    
    // Is null
    if ( is_null( $order->get_date_created() ) ) {
        $order->set_date_created( new WC_DateTime() );
    }
    
    // Get date created
    $date_created = $order->get_date_created()->date( 'Ymd' );

    return $prefix . $order_number . '-' . $date_created;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_number', 'filter_woocommerce_order_number', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: ohh it works. thanks, you save me a lot of time!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

Replace this lines.

```
 $order_date = $order->get_date_created();
 $date_created = $order_date->date( 'Ymd' );
```

To

```
$date_created = $order->get_date_created()->date('Ymd');
```